# ios 9 go back after [UIApplication openURL:] programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios9, application-lifecycle

I'm writing an iOS app that allows other apps to open it via openURL.

Once done I want to send the user back where he came from without having him to press any button (including back).

How can I do this, if its possible ?

To be clear I want to maintain the status of the calling app. So using openURL again is not an option because I will lose context that way

Comment: openURL is the only option AFAIK

Comment: Let's hope there is some other way :)

Comment: There is no (other) way to switch apps.